# Where does Quickly get the PPA name from?

Tags: ppa, application-development, quickly

I am trying to publish an app with Quickly:

```
$ quickly share
Get Launchpad Settings
Launchpad connection is ok
ppa:umpirsky:ppa does not exist. Please create it on launchpad if you want to push a package to it. umpirsky has the following ppas available:
revision-monitor - Revision Monitor
You can temporary choose one of them with --ppa switch or definitely by executing 'quickly configure ppa <ppa_name>'.
ERROR: share command failed
Aborting
```

but it uses a wrong PPA name: it takes `umpirsky`, and I want `revision-monitor`.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

quickly reads the PPA name from the`.quickly` file in the root project directory. It looks like:

```
project = foo
version = 11.10
template = ubuntu-application
ppa = experimental
```

Though by default, the PPA is not set and quickly will assume that you want to use `ppa:launchpad_username/ppa` as that is also the default when registering your first PPA on Launchpad.

As the error message suggests, use `quickly configure ppa <ppa_name>` to change the default. In your case, I think you want:

`quickly configure ppa umpirsky/revision-monitor`

Or you can manually add the line `ppa = revision-monitor` to `.quickly`