# Why does quickly keep submitting to the wrong PPA?

Tags: application-development, ppa, quickly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does Quickly get the PPA name from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96472/where-does-quickly-get-the-ppa-name-from)

I am trying to upload my application for Ubuntu app showdown and I have built it with quickly package --extras, however when I run quickly submit ubuntu I get an email telling me the package was rejected because it was trying to upload to an older ppa I deleted months ago.

I can upload the source to the right area with dput, but obviously I need a built deb package.

This is starting to stress me out somewhat because I have been fighting this for over a day or more now.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I understand quickly is supposed to do a lot of the grunt work for me so it's getting frustrating not knowing what's going on.

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: Have you tried quickly configure?

Comment: Yes, my issue is I can't seem to get the right ppa to work.

I have set the ppa = line in the .quickly file to be ppa = liberedit, but that has resulted in my changes being rejected again.

Comment: Maybe, I found that thread after trawling the site for more information and tried the suggestions, none worked.

Comment: I fixed this by running the quickly configure ppa command and manually changing the file afterwords.